# Replace row values with other row values from same df based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas, replace, conditional-statements, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataset:

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {'user': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 2, 6: 2}, 
    'date': {0: '1995-09-01', 1: '1995-09-02', 2: '1995-10-03', 3: '1995-10-04', 4: '1995-10-05', 5: '1995-11-07', 6: '1995-11-08'}, 
    'x': {0: '1995-09-02', 1: '1995-09-02', 2: '1995-09-02', 3: '1995-10-05', 4: '1995-10-05', 5: '1995-10-05', 6: '1995-10-05'}, 
    'y': {0: '1995-10-03', 1: '1995-10-03', 2: '1995-10-03', 3: '1995-11-08', 4: '1995-11-08', 5: '1995-11-08', 6: '1995-11-08'}, 
    'c1': {0: '1', 1: '0', 2: '0', 3: '2', 4: '0', 5: '9', 6: '0'}, 
    'c2': {0: '1', 1: '0', 2: '0', 3: '2', 4: '0', 5: '9', 6: '0'}, 
    'c3': {0: '1', 1: '0', 2: '0', 3: '2', 4: '0', 5: '9', 6: '0'}, 
    'VTX1': {0: 1, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 1, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0}, 
    'VTY1': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 1, 6: 0}} )
```

which gives me:

```
    user    date         x           y     c1   c2 c3 VTX1 VTY1
0   1   1995-09-01  1995-09-02  1995-10-03  1   1   1   1   0
1   1   1995-09-02  1995-09-02  1995-10-03  0   0   0   0   1
2   1   1995-10-03  1995-09-02  1995-10-03  0   0   0   0   0
3   2   1995-10-04  1995-10-05  1995-11-08  2   2   2   1   0
4   2   1995-10-05  1995-10-05  1995-11-08  0   0   0   0   0
5   2   1995-11-07  1995-10-05  1995-11-08  9   9   9   0   1
6   2   1995-11-08  1995-10-05  1995-11-08  0   0   0   0   0
```

I want to replaces df[‘c1’] as follows.

```
- When df[‘date’]=df[‘x’], 
       change df[‘c1’] for the df[‘c1’] value when df[‘VTX1’]=1
```

In this example, for user 1, when df[‘date’]=df[‘x’] it happens to be on index 1. Here we want df['c1'] to be 1. Note that 1 is the value that user 1 has on df['c1'] when df['VTX1'] = 1.

So the end result would be:

```
   user    date          x         y       c1   c2 c3  VTX1 VTY1
0   1   1995-09-01  1995-09-02  1995-10-03  1   1   1   1   0
1   1   1995-09-02  1995-09-02  1995-10-03  0   0   0   0   1
2   1   1995-10-03  1995-09-02  1995-10-03  0   0   0   0   0
3   2   1995-10-04  1995-10-05  1995-11-08  2   2   2   1   0
4   2   1995-10-05  1995-10-05  1995-11-08  2   0   0   0   0
5   2   1995-11-07  1995-10-05  1995-11-08  9   9   9   0   1
6   2   1995-11-08  1995-10-05  1995-11-08  0   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: For the first condition `df[‘date’]=df[‘x’]...` doesnot match for any row, can you explain how does it match with the second row?

Comment: @anky true, amended accordingly

Comment: In each group can there be more than one `VTX1` value which is equal to `1`?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma in each user group there is only 1 entry with VTX equal to 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each unique user select the row where the column `VTX1` has the value `1`, this can be done by setting the index to `user` and using `query` to select the required rows. Then `mask` the values in `c1` where `date` is equal `x` and substitute the masked values using the mapping series `d`

```
d = df.set_index('user').query('VTX1 == 1')['c1']
df['c1'] = df['c1'].mask(df['date'].eq(df['x']), df['user'].map(d))
```

---

```
   user        date           x           y c1 c2 c3  VTX1  VTY1
0     1  1995-09-01  1995-09-02  1995-10-03  1  1  1     1     0
1     1  1995-09-02  1995-09-02  1995-10-03  1  0  0     0     1
2     1  1995-10-03  1995-09-02  1995-10-03  0  0  0     0     0
3     2  1995-10-04  1995-10-05  1995-11-08  2  2  2     1     0
4     2  1995-10-05  1995-10-05  1995-11-08  2  0  0     0     0
5     2  1995-11-07  1995-10-05  1995-11-08  9  9  9     0     1
6     2  1995-11-08  1995-10-05  1995-11-08  0  0  0     0     0
```